# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS unattended-upgrade killed my mail

Tags: postfix, clamav, amavisd-new

OK, I have Kolab 16 as my mail package on top of a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Kolab (v16) includes clamav, roundcubemail, postfix, amavis and some other bits to tie it all together. It's worked rather well until two days ago when I got an unattended-upgrade pushed onto my machine. After that, it stopped accepting new email (or so it seems). It also no longer sends mail either.

I am open to any help on this.

### Here's the upgrade log:

```
Start-Date: 2020-05-22  06:27:48
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libclamav9:amd64 (0.102.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 0.102.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-05-22  06:27:50

Start-Date: 2020-05-22  06:27:52
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: clamav:amd64 (0.102.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 0.102.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-05-22  06:27:55

Start-Date: 2020-05-22  06:27:57
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: qemu-system-x86:amd64 (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.25, 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.26), qemu-kvm:amd64 (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.25, 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.26)
End-Date: 2020-05-22  06:28:02

Start-Date: 2020-05-22  06:28:04
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: qemu-utils:amd64 (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.25, 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.26), qemu-block-extra:amd64 (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.25, 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.26), qemu-system-common:amd64 (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.25, 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.26)
End-Date: 2020-05-22  06:28:12

Start-Date: 2020-05-22  06:28:15
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: clamav-daemon:amd64 (0.102.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 0.102.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), clamdscan:amd64 (0.102.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 0.102.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), clamav-base:amd64 (0.102.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 0.102.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-05-22  06:28:31

Start-Date: 2020-05-22  06:28:33
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: clamav-freshclam:amd64 (0.102.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 0.102.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-05-22  06:28:39

Start-Date: 2020-05-22  06:28:41
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libvirt-clients:amd64 (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.16, 4.0.0-1ubuntu8.17), libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd:amd64 (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.16, 4.0.0-1ubuntu8.17), libvirt-daemon-system:amd64 (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.16, 4.0.0-1ubuntu8.17), libvirt0:amd64 (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.16, 4.0.0-1ubuntu8.17), libvirt-daemon:amd64 (4.0.0-1ubuntu8.16, 4.0.0-1ubuntu8.17)
End-Date: 2020-05-22  06:29:03
```

---

Here's the 'clamconf" output

```
# ./clamconf
Checking configuration files in /etc/clamav

Config file: clamd.conf
-----------------------
AlertExceedsMax disabled
PreludeEnable disabled
PreludeAnalyzerName = "ClamAV"
LogFile = "/var/log/clamav/clamav.log"
LogFileUnlock disabled
LogFileMaxSize = "4294967295"
LogTime = "yes"
LogClean disabled
LogSyslog disabled
LogFacility = "LOG_LOCAL6"
LogVerbose disabled
LogRotate = "yes"
ExtendedDetectionInfo = "yes"
PidFile disabled
TemporaryDirectory disabled
DatabaseDirectory = "/var/lib/clamav"
OfficialDatabaseOnly disabled
LocalSocket = "/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl"
LocalSocketGroup = "clamav"
LocalSocketMode = "666"
FixStaleSocket = "yes"
TCPSocket disabled
TCPAddr disabled
MaxConnectionQueueLength = "15"
StreamMaxLength = "26214400"
StreamMinPort = "1024"
StreamMaxPort = "2048"
MaxThreads = "12"
ReadTimeout = "180"
CommandReadTimeout = "30"
SendBufTimeout = "200"
MaxQueue = "100"
IdleTimeout = "30"
ExcludePath disabled
MaxDirectoryRecursion = "15"
FollowDirectorySymlinks disabled
FollowFileSymlinks disabled
CrossFilesystems = "yes"
SelfCheck = "3600"
DisableCache disabled
VirusEvent disabled
ExitOnOOM disabled
AllowAllMatchScan = "yes"
Foreground disabled
Debug disabled
LeaveTemporaryFiles disabled
User = "clamav"
Bytecode = "yes"
BytecodeSecurity = "TrustSigned"
BytecodeTimeout = "60000"
BytecodeUnsigned disabled
BytecodeMode = "Auto"
DetectPUA disabled
ExcludePUA disabled
IncludePUA disabled
ScanPE = "yes"
ScanELF = "yes"
ScanMail = "yes"
ScanPartialMessages disabled
PhishingSignatures = "yes"
PhishingScanURLs = "yes"
HeuristicAlerts = "yes"
HeuristicScanPrecedence disabled
StructuredDataDetection disabled
StructuredMinCreditCardCount = "3"
StructuredMinSSNCount = "3"
StructuredSSNFormatNormal = "yes"
StructuredSSNFormatStripped disabled
ScanHTML = "yes"
ScanOLE2 = "yes"
AlertBrokenExecutables disabled
AlertEncrypted disabled
AlertEncryptedArchive disabled
AlertEncryptedDoc disabled
AlertOLE2Macros disabled
AlertPhishingSSLMismatch disabled
AlertPhishingCloak disabled
AlertPartitionIntersection disabled
ScanPDF = "yes"
ScanSWF = "yes"
ScanXMLDOCS = "yes"
ScanHWP3 = "yes"
ScanArchive = "yes"
ForceToDisk disabled
MaxScanTime = "120000"
MaxScanSize = "104857600"
MaxFileSize = "26214400"
MaxRecursion = "16"
MaxFiles = "10000"
MaxEmbeddedPE = "10485760"
MaxHTMLNormalize = "10485760"
MaxHTMLNoTags = "2097152"
MaxScriptNormalize = "5242880"
MaxZipTypeRcg = "1048576"
MaxPartitions = "50"
MaxIconsPE = "100"
MaxRecHWP3 = "16"
PCREMatchLimit = "10000"
PCRERecMatchLimit = "5000"
PCREMaxFileSize = "26214400"
OnAccessMountPath disabled
OnAccessIncludePath disabled
OnAccessExcludePath disabled
OnAccessExcludeRootUID disabled
OnAccessExcludeUID disabled
OnAccessExcludeUname disabled
OnAccessMaxFileSize = "5242880"
OnAccessDisableDDD disabled
OnAccessPrevention disabled
OnAccessExtraScanning disabled
OnAccessCurlTimeout = "5000"
OnAccessMaxThreads = "5"
OnAccessRetryAttempts disabled
OnAccessDenyOnError disabled
DevACOnly disabled
DevACDepth disabled
DevPerformance disabled
DevLiblog disabled
DisableCertCheck disabled
AlgorithmicDetection = "yes"
BlockMax disabled
PhishingAlwaysBlockSSLMismatch disabled
PhishingAlwaysBlockCloak disabled
PartitionIntersection disabled
OLE2BlockMacros disabled
ArchiveBlockEncrypted disabled

Config file: freshclam.conf
---------------------------
LogFileMaxSize = "4294967295"
LogTime = "yes"
LogSyslog disabled
LogFacility = "LOG_LOCAL6"
LogVerbose disabled
LogRotate = "yes"
PidFile disabled
DatabaseDirectory = "/var/lib/clamav"
Foreground disabled
Debug disabled
UpdateLogFile = "/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log"
DatabaseOwner = "clamav"
Checks = "24"
DNSDatabaseInfo = "current.cvd.clamav.net"
DatabaseMirror = "db.local.clamav.net", "database.clamav.net"
PrivateMirror disabled
MaxAttempts = "5"
ScriptedUpdates = "yes"
TestDatabases = "yes"
CompressLocalDatabase disabled
ExtraDatabase disabled
ExcludeDatabase disabled
DatabaseCustomURL disabled
HTTPProxyServer disabled
HTTPProxyPort disabled
HTTPProxyUsername disabled
HTTPProxyPassword disabled
HTTPUserAgent disabled
NotifyClamd = "/etc/clamav/clamd.conf"
OnUpdateExecute disabled
OnErrorExecute disabled
OnOutdatedExecute disabled
LocalIPAddress disabled
ConnectTimeout = "30"
ReceiveTimeout = "30"
SafeBrowsing disabled
Bytecode = "yes"

clamav-milter.conf not found

Software settings
-----------------
Version: 0.102.3
Optional features supported: MEMPOOL IPv6 FRESHCLAM_DNS_FIX AUTOIT_EA06 BZIP2 LIBXML2 PCRE ICONV JSON JIT

Database information
--------------------
Database directory: /var/lib/clamav
daily.cld: version 25821, sigs: 2465067, built on Sat May 23 05:21:31 2020
bytecode.cvd: version 331, sigs: 94, built on Thu Sep 19 09:12:33 2019
main.cvd: version 59, sigs: 4564902, built on Mon Nov 25 05:56:15 2019
Total number of signatures: 7030063

Platform information
--------------------
uname: Linux 4.15.0-101-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 11 10:07:26 UTC 2020 x86_64
OS: linux-gnu, ARCH: x86_64, CPU: x86_64
Full OS version: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
zlib version: 1.2.11 (1.2.11), compile flags: a9
Triple: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
CPU: ivybridge, Little-endian
platform id: 0x0a2172720807050001070500

Build information
-----------------
GNU C: 7.5.0 (7.5.0)
GNU C++: 7.5.0 (7.5.0)
CPPFLAGS: -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/clamav-pK3ANb/clamav-0.102.3+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
CXXFLAGS: -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/clamav-pK3ANb/clamav-0.102.3+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
LDFLAGS: -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed
Configure: '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--runstatedir=/run' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/clamav-pK3ANb/clamav-0.102.3+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/clamav-pK3ANb/clamav-0.102.3+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed' '--with-dbdir=/var/lib/clamav' '--sysconfdir=/etc/clamav' '--disable-clamav' '--disable-unrar' '--enable-milter' '--enable-dns-fix' '--with-libjson' '--with-system-libmspack' '--with-libcurl=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '-with-system-llvm=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.9' '--with-llvm-linking=dynamic' '--with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'OBJCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/clamav-pK3ANb/clamav-0.102.3+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
sizeof(void*) = 8
Engine flevel: 114, dconf: 114
```

Comment: @Mitch... I don't know if it's OK to post large file contents like this?

Comment: Hi Tom, how do you know your machine isn't accepting mail?

Comment: It is accepting mail- Postfix is happy to take in the mail, as testing shows. It never gets to the intended user's mail directory. That stopped happening when ubuntu pushed down that unattended-upgrade. Now I have no idea where all the mails have gone, but it keeps accepting them.

Comment: ** I found the fix**- it turns out that the upgrade had deleted my amavis config file. Once I discovered that, I copied in the template file from the kolab install folder, and rebooted. All is good now. Thanks to everyone for their help on this. How can I mark this as fixed?